# Regex for PBXProject files

Tags: ruby, regex

Working on pure-ruby implementation of XCode project file parser, [PBXProject](https://github.com/owlforestry/pbxproject), and need little help with regex.

So the PBXProject file has bunch of weird coed lines, which mixed contents. What I have now is regex, `(.*?) = (.*?)( \/\* (.*) \*\/)?; ?` which works on simpler cases (first line). But for second line, it cuts too early (to first ; -character).

```
isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = C0480C2015F4F91F00E0A2F4 /* zip.c */;

isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = C0480C2315F4F91F00E0A2F4 /* ZipArchive.mm */; settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = "-fno-objc-arc"; };
```

So what I want out of those lines are simple `name = value` pairs, i.e.

```
isa = PBXBuildFile
settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = "-fno-objc-arc"; }
```

Easy way to achieve this with one regex?

Comment: Do you not want to get `fileRef = C0480C2315F4F91F00E0A2F4` part?

Comment: Yes I want that part as well, as comments. Those were simple examples which parts I need separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work just fine:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*?=\s*?.*?(?:{[^}]*}|(?=;))
```

Note that only one level of brackets is allowed, the regex will not process nested brackets.

From your example, the following lines will be catched:

```
isa = PBXBuildFile
fileRef = C0480C2015F4F91F00E0A2F4 /* zip.c */
isa = PBXBuildFile
fileRef = C0480C2315F4F91F00E0A2F4 /* ZipArchive.mm */
settings = {COMPILER_FLAGS = "-fno-objc-arc"; }
```

Here's the explanation of regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*?=\s*?.*?(?:{[^}]*}|(?=;))

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z0-9]*»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
    A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
    A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
    A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*?»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “=” literally «=»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*?»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
    Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the regular expression below «(?:(?={){[^}]*}|(?=;))»
    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?={){[^}]*}»
        Match the character “{” literally «{»
        Match any character that is NOT a “}” «[^}]*»
            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
        Match the character “}” literally «}»
    Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?=;)»
        Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=;)»
            Match the character “;” literally «;»
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked just fine, with some modifications to separate comments I got /(\S*?) = (\s*?(.*?)(?:(?={){[^}]*}|(?: \/\* (.*?) \*\/)?(?=;)))/ And huge thanks for the explanation, that definitely helps me to learn regexp better =)

Comment: You're welcome! [Here's a nice tool](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) which you can use to explain your regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact nature of the content you wish to parse, it may not be possible with a single finite expression. The second line you are having trouble with indicates that there might be nested patterns involved. A nested pattern can only be matched up to a finite depth which is one of the reasons why it is not advised to parse [X]HTML with regex. If you actually want to handle arbitrarily deep nesting, you might want to look into something like [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/).

If you don't need it to be robust, you could try an expression like this:

```
/((?i)(?:[^;]+=\s*\{.*?\})|[^;]+=[^;]+);/
```

which will first try to match something of the form `something = {anything}`, and if unsuccessful, it will match `something = something` before a `;`. You should be able to use `string.scan(/regex/)` to find all the matches for a given string. Handling the blocks in this way should avoid problems such as prematurely ending the matching process and you can extract the pairs easily.

Further reading:

- [Regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar)
- [Context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)

Comment: Thanks for reminding of treetop, that's definitely something I should check out if that would make parsing those files easier...